# How to update a record the proper way?

Tags: mongoose, express

I'm writing a backbone app with Express/NodeJs backend which relies on mongoDb (via mongoose) for storage.

Time has come to update records in the database and I'm hitting a wall.

The code I've written is: https://gist.github.com/b90130f640cea75b0cbd

I understand that the error preventing the update is due the fact I am passing all the fields, including the non modifiable "_id" one.

What I am asking is: Is there any way I can pass all the fields to the update method, or do I
have to specify them one by one (or iterate through all of them)?

Thanks in advance for your help, regards.

Answer (score 2):

you could delete the _id before passing it to `model.update()`

Answer (score 2):

You can just upsert instead of update.

```
new User(req.body).save();
```

Anyways, excepting that req.body will have the correct data could cause security issues depending on how your models are (GitHub had a problem like this recently).

My advice is to get only what you want from req.body and update.

```
var updateData = {
  name: req.body.name
};
User.update({_id: user._id},updateData, function(err,affected) {
  console.log('affected rows %d', affected);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno for the upsert pointer! Totally slipped out of my sight. Perhaps, in the end, it would be better trying to go the second route by means of a "dirty field tracking" on the backbonejs side.